# Find next Quarter/Month/Year/Bi-annual Date from Pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, date, offset

I want to find a way that could give me next month/quarter/year/bi-annual date given a Pandas timestamp.

If the timestamp is already an end of month/quarter/year/bi-annual date than I can get next quarter date as follows:

```
pd.Timestamp('1999-12-31') + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
```

What if the time stamp was `pd.Timestamp('1999-12-30')`, the above won't work.

**Expected output**

```
input = pd.Timestamp('1999-12-30')
next_quarter_end = '2000-03-31'
next_month_end = '2000-01-31'
next_year_end = '2000-12-31'
next_biannual_end = '2000-06-30'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. I used [`pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html), [`.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html), and [`.YearEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.YearEnd.html), multiplied by specific factors that change based on the input, to achieve the four values you're looking for.

```py
date = pd.Timestamp('1999-12-31')
month_factor = 1 if date.day == date.days_in_month else 2
year_factor = 1 if date.day == date.days_in_month and date.month == 12 else 2
next_month_end = date + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd() * month_factor
next_quarter_end = date + (pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd() * month_factor)
next_year_end = date + pd.tseries.offsets.YearEnd() * year_factor
next_biannual_end = date + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the next quarter end after `Timestamp('1999-12-30')` is `Timestamp('1999-12-31 00:00:00')`

You can use `pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd`

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('1999-12-30') + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
Timestamp('1999-12-31 00:00:00')

>>> pd.Timestamp('1999-12-30') + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()*2
Timestamp('2000-03-31 00:00:00')
```

Similarly, use `pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()` and `pandas.tseries.offsets.YearEnd()`

For biannual, I guess you can take `2*QuarterEnd()`.

Comment: @mozway the accepted solution is more robust and covers up both the scenario.

Comment: @Lopez no worries, I also upvoted this answer ;)